# Restrict ReplayKit from recording photo gallery/ DocumentPicker when recording the app

Tags: swift, replaykit, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller, phpickerviewcontroller

I have a requirement where I want to screenshare the app's screen to the participants in the meeting in the app. I use ReplayKit to record the app's screen. However, I want to restrict recording the PHPickerViewController/UIImagePickerViewController/UIDocumentPickerViewController if user opens during the screenshare as it would have sensitive information. Can someone please guide me what is the correct approach to achieve this?

I have checked to see if any app lifecycle event gets triggered when these viewcontrollers are opened in the app but found that none of them gets triggered at this point. Mine is an sdk integrated in the app and as sdk I would not know when the use user opens these screen from the app.